# iOS 8 widget (today extension) with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, widget, uicollectionview, ios-app-extension

Have anyone tried to add UICollectionView to iOS 8 Widget ([Today Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1)) ?

Once I do this, Notification Center crashs. 
Without UICollectionView it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating to the latest Xcode 6 beta 5